# Python Selenium: how to change "disabled" attribute to "enabled"

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I use this code:

```
commit = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div[1]/div[4]/button")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('enabled', true)", commit)
```

But the attribute does not change.

I guess I'm using the `.execute_script()` function incorrectly.

I can change this attribute manually and it will give the result I want. Shown in screenshots:
[image]
[image]

How can i change this attribute with Selenium?

P.S. XPATH is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This helped in this case:

```
commit = self.driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div[1]/div[4]/button")
self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].disabled = false", commit)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to notice.

1. `driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH` should be

   ```
   driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "XPath here")
   ```
2. Do not use absolute xpath, instead use relative path.

   ```
   //button[@type='submit' and contains(@class,'gtm_reg_btn') and @disabled]
   ```

You will have to make sure that, it in unique in HTMLDOM.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

Bit of change you will have to make here:

Instead of this:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('enabled', true)", commit)
```

Use this:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('disabled','enabled')", commit)
```

Comment: Dont work.
In my situation I need to use exactly absolute xpath.

Comment: Well, if you read the answer carefully I have mentioned that the XPath should be unique in nature.

Comment: It's not about that. Moreover, I have already answered my own question.